# how to check custom string format contains '/'

Tags: php, regex

I have a text input that  search subjectid,subjectname , semester/year and want to search everything in a single input.

```
1/2010


-/----
```

I need to check the result is true or false .
How to do that?

Comment: You mean [`strpos`](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) ?

Comment: but I dont know how to check position using strpos.

Comment: `if(strpos($customstring,'/')!==false) { echo "Found Slash"; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semester is 1 or 2 so you could use:

```
if (preg_match('#\b[12]/\d{4}\b#', $string)) {
    echo "match\n";
}
```

`\b` is a word boundary, assumes there're no word char before the digit
`[12]`  matches digit 1 or 2
`/`  is literaly `/`
`\d{4}` matches 4 digits
`\b` is a word boundary, assumes there're no word char after the digits

Answer (score 0):

If you're checking for a specific format, I'd suggest a regex.
`[0-9]/[0-9]{4}` will match any number followed by a "/" followed by 4 numbers.  If you want letters and numbers, then `[0-9a-zA-Z]/[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}` will match that.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote the regex to be visually simple - but the explanation of regex and implementation in M42's answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). And do an if else statement.

```
if (strpos($string, '/') == false) //the '/' does not exist
  execute code
else
  execute code
```